# tracklang.sty missing in miktex

Tags: packages

I use MiKTeX 2.9.5105 32bit with Texmaker or TechnicCenter and with both of these programs I get an error while compiling:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `tracklang.sty' not found. Type X to quit or
>    to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty) Enter
>   file name: ! Emergency stop.

The missing packages should be downloaded automatically which is not the case for this one. Plus I installed the missing package by hand and still it is not finding the missing file.

Does any of you have an idea how to solve this Problem?

Comment: On-the-fly installation worked fine for me. Is your package database up-to-date? (If in doubt: menu `repositories -> synchronize` in the package manager (admin *and* user version).

Comment: I solved it by updating the packages first (miktex update) and then installing the tracklang package manually via the miktex package Manager. The Problem before updating the packages was, that the tracklang package was not available in the package Manager. Thanks anyway!