# New error using glossaries package / tracklang.sty

Tags: glossaries

I used glossaries package many times. Recently I restart my computer and I reinstall MiKTeX/TeXstudio. When I try to compile (an old) .tex file I receive this error

File `tracklang.sty` not found. `\@gls@usetranslator`
You have requested release **2014/05/01** of LaTeX, but only release **2011/06/27** is available.

Anyone know what happen? Thanks!

Comment: This might help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220924/tracklang-sty-missing-in-miktex

Comment: I was getting this error too, though with `texlive` on Ubuntu. The solution was to install the package `texlive-generic-extra`, which includes `tracklang`. Just for the record...