# Error in Latex using texmaker ubuntu 16 tracklang.sty

Tags: glossaries

I am using glossaries in texmaker in ubuntu 16.04 and when I tried to compile and old project that was working in ubuntu 14.04 and I got this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `tracklang.sty' not found.Type X to quit or
>    to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter
>   file name:! Emergency stop. \@gls@usetranslator

I found these similar questions: [Question1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220924/tracklang-sty-missing-in-miktex), [question2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/new-error-using-glossaries-package-tracklang-sty) but they are for windows (MiKTeX)

Comment: Welcome. It seems that the package https://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang was not installed. 
Please consider to add ad MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that.

Comment: @CampanIgnis sorry I didn't put a minimal example, but sometimes is complicated to extract the error from a huge document that was already working on another computer.

Answer (score 5):

as @CampanIgnis suggested the missing package was [tracklang](https://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang) I found it in [texlive-plain-generic](https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-plain-generic). I install it as:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-generic-extra
```

Comment: This is the cause but isn't that explicit already in the error message that you put in the question?

Comment: On Arch Linux, install `texlive-plaingeneric`.